# Not able to generate auth token inJMeter while in PostMan, it is working fine

Tags: oauth, jmeter

I am trying to generate auth token in Jmeter but getting error message:

> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"There is no client
>   authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter."}

despite working fine in PostMan. I am also providing the Headerbody and Header Manager.

Do I need to do anything else while working on JMEter. Please help I am not able to understand despite my efforts.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show JSON response

Comment: added the all images...please check..one of them is a json response

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Parameters` tab in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, not the `Body Data`, try converting your request to look like:

[image]

---

Going forward be aware that you should be normally able to **record** the Postman request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

1. Configure JMeter for recording using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature

   [image]
2. Start HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Execute the request - JMeter will capture it and store under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T for your respons. I had tried the first option already but definitely will try second option i.e. recording and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the 'Parameters' tab or 'Body Data' tab of the HTTP request sampler to enter request body. Find below screenshot showing both the ways:

- **Body Data Tab**

[image: Body Data]

- **Parameters Tab**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your response but sorry to say that i had tried these but no luck as i have attached the snapshots also.